# How to customize the field tabindex in Odoo 12

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I have following Odoo form view:

```
<group class="o_group_col_4">
 <field name="start_time"/>
 <field name="finish_time"/>
 <field name="readonly_field1" attrs="{'readonly':True}"/>
</group>
<group class="o_group_col_4">
 <field name="readonly_field2"  attrs="{'readonly':True}"/>
 <field name="date"/>
</group>
```

In the form view when I press TAB key from `start_time`, it goes to `end_time` but form `end_time` it does not go to date field on TAB.

Can anyone help how can we specify tabindex in odoo form view, so that the TAB navigation becomes `start_time` -> `end_time` -> `date`?

Comment: I have same issue